# Flutter, prevent Text automatically break the lines

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I do not want the text to break the lines.

Code is below:

```
     return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
       child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(100.0),
         child: Container(child: Text("Werwerwer eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee ddddddd dd ddddddddddddddddd")),
      ),
     ),
    );
```

and the picture is below:

[image: Picture! :D]

The red lines are all just blanks which are I do not want.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think because you use too large padding (100). So the horizon padding check it need to change the line because out of space.

You can use Debug Paint and see how padding work:
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/devtools/inspector

Try to change the padding to a lower value, or use **EdgeInsets.symmetric**,  **EdgeInsets.only** or **EdgeInsets.fromLTRB** if you want to use different padding on left, top, right, bottom

[padding with debug paint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wBUo.jpg)

Comment: no .. this has nothing to do with that padding (0) is totally same

Comment: Have you try to turn on the Debug Paint in Flutter Inspector ? I attach the screen will looks like when you turn it on. Is show a blue area what your padding do. It surely work fine on my side so if it not working from your side, you may need to provide the full code.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding. this is very common problem in flutter I guess when next word is too long for next space then break the lines this is the problem. In English  grammar, this is not the problem but other languages having problem with this

Comment: Please suggest what you want in the result. Do you want to show only one line? You can try to change 'softWrap' to false or 'overflow' behavior in Text Widget. Or you just want it not breaking the line by 'Space'? you may need to replace all space to "Non-breaking space". Like "Werwerwer eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee ddddddd dd ddddddddddddddddd".replaceAll(' ', '\u00A0'). More info here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your **Text widget** in a **Flexible widget** rather than a Container
and consider adjusting your padding

```
return Scaffold(
  body: Center(
   child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(100.0),// alternatively try using EdgeInsets.symmetric()
     child: Flexible(child: Text("This is a Loooooooooooong Text")),
  ),
 ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(100.0),
          child: Container(
            child: Text(
              "Werwerwer eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee ddddddd dd ddddddddddddddddd"
                  .replaceAll(' ', '\u00A0'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: hi Ali, in RichText, "replaceAll(' ', '\u00A0')" seems not working, do you know how to figure out this in many texts situations?